# MSALJS version 1.2.1 loginRedirect does not invoke handleRedirectCallback when site is deployed

Tags: authentication, redirect, msal.js

I am trying to get loginRedirect working with a React app.  It works when running locally, but when I deploy to Azure App Service, then the redirect does not invoke handleRedirectCallback(), and the hash stays in the Url.

So I have kept reducing this until now I have just an index.html, which I have taken from here: 
  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/blob/master/index.html

This is from Micrososft's ADB2C With MSAL and SPA.

I changed the clientId and authority, provided a handleRedirectCallback and redirectUri, and changed myMSALObj.loginPopup() to myMSALObj.loginRedirect().

When I run locally, it works, although it executes 2 times (breakpoint on new UserAgentApplication(config)).

PROBLEM: When I deploy this simple page to Azure App Service, and click Login, the call to

```
myMSALObj.loginRedirect()
```

does navigate to the Microsoft login, but when it redirects back to my site and executes

```
new UserAgentApplication(config)
```

it does not fire handleRedirectCallback(), and does not consume the window.location.hash.  The hash stays on the Url, and processing just stops.

I can set breakpoints in the deployed source (in Chrome Dev) and observe that after redirecting back to my page, it is definitely newing UserAgentApplication, but it never comes back from the constructor.

Here's the essential code from index.html, not showing the part that calls an Api etc:

```
  <script>
    "use strict";

    // configuration to initialize msal
    const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx", //This is your client ID
            authority: "https://xxxxxxxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin", 
            validateAuthority: false,
            redirectUri: 'https://xxxxxxxxx-react.azurewebsites.net'
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true
        }
    };

    // instantiate MSAL
    const myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
    myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback((err, response) => {
      if (err) {
          alert(err);
      } else {
          updateUI();
      }
      });

    const loginRequest = {
        scopes: appConfig.b2cScopes
    };

    function signIn() {
        // myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest).then(function (loginResponse) {
        //     getToken(tokenRequest).then(updateUI);
        // }).catch(function (error) {
        //     logMessage(error);
        // });
        myMSALObj.loginRedirect(loginRequest)
    }

    function updateUI() {
        console.log('inside updateUI');
      const userName = myMSALObj.getAccount().name;
      console.log(myMSALObj.getAccount());
      console.log('username=' + userName);
      logMessage("User '" + userName + "' logged-in");
    }

</script>
```

The Azure App Service is Linux running PHP 7.3.

Comment: After 2 days of this not working, I wrote this stackoverflow question and gave up.  Then I thought I would try it on my Android phone, and it worked.  So I got out my laptop, and it worked.  So this morning I try it on my company laptop, and now it works.

Somehow, writing this stackoverflow question fixed it?

I did not change anything.    It even works on the older branch with the full React/useContext/useEffect/PrivateRoutes version.  I did not change anything in my Azure resources either.  I cannot explain this.

Comment: I am quite fearfull now that it is gong to magically stop working now just as it magically started working.  If anyone has any thoughts on this subject, even though it now appears to be solved, I am very interested.